# How to control Two chart of highstock with scroll bar

Tags: highcharts

I would like to write a external scroll bar to control two chart or other things for highstock.

And I would like to ask how to control the scroll bar for the chart.
I saw the API, it do not provide a event for it.

I think it can be two solution.

1. Control the navigator or scroll bar to make it move left to right in two chart together.
2. Control the date of rangeSelector

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Any bros can provide a better JS plugin do the similar jobs, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can control charts by [setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes%28%29) function.

Comment: Thanks bro. I saw the function is quite similar to what I want. But I want to move the xAxis to the left by jquery UI sider. Is it possible?